How to increase size of matplotlib sector plot
i have a polar plot with a very tiny angle. But image has size like it is full angle from 0-pi. When i try to decrease fig height, image width also decreases. So how to increase size of this image and place it on figure more effectively?

my script
def plot_density_rtheta(Rho, xmin, xmax, thetamin, thetamax):
    plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 15})
    nx = Rho.shape[0]
    ny = Rho.shape[1]
    f1 = plt.figure(figsize=[10,10])
    rad = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, nx)
    azm = np.linspace(thetamin - np.pi/2, thetamax - np.pi/2, ny)
    r, th = np.meshgrid(rad, azm)
            
    ax = plt.subplot(projection="polar")
    ax.axis("off")

    ax.set_thetamin(thetamin*180/np.pi - 90)
    ax.set_thetamax(thetamax*180/np.pi - 90)

    im2 = plt.pcolormesh(th, r, rho, norm = colors.LogNorm(vmin = minRho, vmax = maxRho))
    cax2 = f1.add_axes([0.125,0.92,0.775,0.03])
    plt.colorbar(im2,cax=cax2,orientation='horizontal')
    plt.savefig('density_rtheta.png')
    plt.close()

